# How to edit remote file with ruby?

Tags: ruby, file-io

I have a remote file on my server, It's writable. I know how to read and edit local files, but I have a problem with remote files. For example: `www.mysite.com/myfile.txt`

Comment: `require 'open-uri'` should let you use `open(remote_file)`, but not seen anything on writing to it; only reading from it.

Comment: Does your server support webdav? How would your write that file?

Comment: I run my script from my local pc. the file is on server that use php and apache

Comment: @user111701: You should have already told us what kind of protocol your web server supports for editing files.  FTP?  SFTP?  SCP?  rsync?  You will most likely have to download the file to your local computer, edit it, and then upload it using the appropriate protocol/hostname/username/password.

Comment: @David Grayson :  I have to use http protocol .There is not any choise.My problem is I cant upload the file again. I need to edit it while it is on the server.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way of using HTTP to edit a file, so you will have to:

1. Write a PHP script that accepts HTTP requests with data in them and writes the data to the file.  You will probably want some form of security and you will probably need to mark the file as writable by all (`chmod a+w`*`filename`*).  You will probably want it to be a POST request so the file length is not limited by the max length of a URI.
2. Make a little HTML form to test the script.
3. Write a ruby script that sends that HTTP request. The [built-in `Net::HTTP` library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) will probably work for you.